# Structuring Active Record Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So I have one table (`Orders`) and I want to put together a query like such:

```
Order.where(ship_day: today).where(!User.find(order.user_id).payment_information.nil?)
```

Any ideas as to how I contruct this in rails?

Comment: what are you hoping to get as results?

Comment: Is table1.field2 a foreign key to table1? Could you actually give us more details on what you want to get?

Comment: @dax Just updated the post. Does that help?

Comment: @Drew - a bit.  i can now make an inference to answer my own question :p  You want to find orders shipped today that the user has paid for? is that right?

Comment: @dax Cool. Or orders that are to be shipped today where the user to whom the order is to be shipped also has the information needed to process a payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Order.where(ship_day: DateTime.now.to_date).joins(:user).where('user.payment_information IS NOT ?', nil)
```